# Assigning graph attributes using a function in R

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

I am working on a set of functions that will allow me to plot network data in various ways. Because some procedures are being used in multiple functions, to avoid copying and pasting I try to turn such procedures into mini-function that I can then simply recall whenever necessary.

Right now I got stuck with a mini-function that would decorate my graph based on attributes. For example I want be able to take a graph

```
toy.graph <- graph.formula(121-221,121-345,121-587,345-587,221-587, 490, 588)
```

and assign to it color. But when I try to use the following function:

```
deco <- function(x){
        V(x)$color <- "red"
}
```

and apply it to my graph the color is not being added:

```
deco(toy.graph)
toy.graph
## IGRAPH UN-- 5 5 -- 
## attr: name (v/c)

V(toy.graph)$color
## NULL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your function is not returning a value.
2. You aren't reassigning the variable when you call the function.

Try:

```
toy.graph <- graph.formula(121-221,121-345,121-587,345-587,221-587, 490, 587)
deco <- function(x){
        V(x)$color <- "red"
        return(x)
}
toy.graph <- deco(toy.graph)
plot(toy.graph)
```

If you want to avoid reassigning variables and having your function return a value, you can probably use `eval` inside your function to evaluate `V(x)$color <- "red"` in the parent environment.

**EDIT** fun with environments:

```
toy.graph <- graph.formula(121-221,121-345,121-587,345-587,221-587, 490, 587)        

deco <- function(x) {
  # get actual variable name
  p = deparse(eval(substitute(substitute(x)), parent.frame())) 
  # create expression to evaluate
  e = parse(text = paste0("V(", p, ")$color <- 'red'"))
  # evaluate in parent environment
  eval.parent(e)
}

deco(toy.graph)
plot(toy.graph)
```