# Assigning graph attributes using a function in R using switch()

Tags: r, switch-statement, igraph, vertex-attributes

I have a follow up question to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853814/assigning-graph-attributes-using-a-function-in-r).

I want to build a function that will assign attributes to a graph based on a certain parameter (called `lev` in the example below). Here is my toy graph:

```
toy.graph <- graph.formula(121-221,121-345,121-587,345-587,221-587,490,588)
```

and here is a sample function:

```
deco2 <- function(x, lev){
      switch(lev,
            one = {V(x)$color <- "red"},
            two = {V(x)$color <- "yellow"})
      return(x)
}
```

It seems that the `color` attribute is being added to my graph:

```
toy.graph <- deco2(toy.graph, lev="one")
> toy.graph
IGRAPH UN-- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), color (v/c)
```

However, when I print the values for the attribute it turns out they are not there:

```
> toy.graph$color
NULL
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT** The solution with assigning `y` works perfect when I have just one color. However, I still have issues when I want to assign multiple colors within each `switch` options. Here is my attempt with the `y` assignment:

```
V(toy.graph)$gender <- sample(c("M","F"), 6, replace = TRUE)
V(toy.graph)$gender
[1] "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M"

deco2 <- function(x, lev){
         y <- switch(lev,
             one = {V(x)$color = "red"},
             two = {V(x)[gender == "F"]$color = "yellow"
                    V(x)[gender == "M"]$color = "green"})
         V(x)$color <- y
         return(x)
}
```

For some reason I get assign only the `"green"` color:

```
toy.graph <- deco2(toy.graph, lev="two")
toy.graph
IGRAPH UN-- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), gender (v/c), color (v/c)
V(toy.graph)$color
[1] "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you want:

```
library(igraph)
toy.graph <- graph.formula(121-221,121-345,121-587,345-587,221-587,490,588)

deco2 <- function(x, lev){
  #make sure you assign switch's output to a variable (e.g. y)
  y <-
  switch(lev,
         one =  "red",
         two =  "yellow")
  V(x)$color <- y
  x
}


toy.graph <- deco2(toy.graph, lev="one")

> V(toy.graph)$color
[1] "red" "red" "red" "red" "red" "red"
```

I don't think it is a good idea to assign a value to x inside `switch`. Instead use `switch` for what it has been designed i.e. to return the value corresponding to your input and then in the next step assign that value to your object.

This way it works as expected!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)